# The Wonderful Apps aren't loaded yet Error

Tags: django, python-3.x

I've searched SO and Google and can't find an answer to my problem.

I've launched my virtualenv and ran this command in the terminal:

```
python bin/process_messages.py
```

and this error occurs:

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/process_messages.py", line 6, in <module>
  from xyz.models import get_sku
File "/Users/myname/.environments/xyz_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xyz/models.py", line 19, in <module>
class Suppliers(models.Model):
File "/Users/myname/.environments/xyz_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 110, in __new__
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "/Users/myname/.environments/xyz_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
self.check_apps_ready()
File "/Users/myname/.environments/xyz_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I thought it wasn't running django.setup so I added that to the script. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import django
import boto3
from xyz.settings import SQS_QUEUE_NAME
from xyz.models import get_sku

__author__ = 'me'


def check_django_environment(default_settings):
    # Environment setup for Django project files:
    os.sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
    if not os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'):
        # Don't override settings if it is specified.
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = default_settings
        from django.conf import settings

        return getattr(settings, 'DEBUG', None)

check_django_environment('xyz.settings')
django.setup()

# Get the service resource
sqs = boto3.resource('sqs')

# Get the queue
queue = sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=SQS_QUEUE_NAME)

for message in queue.receive_messages():
    print(message)
    if message.message_attributes is not None:
        print(message.message_attributes)

        #sku = message.message_attributes
        db_sku = get_sku(sku)
        print(db_sku)
    break
```

My Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'xyz',
]
```

Answer (score 2):

By importing `get_sku`, you are importing your models before `django.setup()` has run. You need to move this import down so it happens after `django.setup()`.

In a stand-alone script that uses Django, I generally have two groups of imports. The first contains the bare minimum to get Django setup, the second contains all the other imports, including models etc.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import django

__author__ = 'me'


def check_django_environment(default_settings):
    # Environment setup for Django project files:
    os.sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
    if not os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'):
        # Don't override settings if it is specified.
        os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = default_settings
        from django.conf import settings

        return getattr(settings, 'DEBUG', None)

check_django_environment('xyz.settings')
django.setup()

import boto3
from xyz.settings import SQS_QUEUE_NAME
from xyz.models import get_sku
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to knbk's answer, you can also just use `manage.py`.

Here's an example script, let's say `script.py`:

```
from xyz.models import get_sku

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_sku)
```

And you run it like:

```
./manage.py shell < script.py
```

Maybe not what you're looking for, but worth knowing, nonetheless.